# Add textboxes dynamically in a form, using Jade template engine

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, pug

My requirement is a simple one , but no definite answer is available for this one on the net.
I have  a combobox in my jade page which takes numbers as input.I want the same page to refresh and have as  many textboxes as the number specified. I know this requires Ajax, but I am not able to figure out how it can be used in Jade.Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using ajax with help of jQuery.

Define jade like this

```
input.addTxtBox(type='text')
   #rows
```

and then in javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // initiate layout and plugins
    $('.addTxtBox').keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $('.addTxtBox').val();
        var str = '<input type="text">';
        for(var i=0; i < parseInt(value) ; i++){
            $("#rows").append(str);
        }
    });
});
```

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3AP/1239/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I currently use the Express framework and would have to add the jQuery part to the index.js file(which contains all the routes).